# Opposite helicities of $e^-$ and $\bar{\nu}_e$ from angular momentum conservation in pion decay

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, helicity, pions

Consider the decay $\pi^-\to e^-+\bar{\nu}_e$ in the rest frame of the pion so that $L_\pi=0$. Since the pion is a spin-$0$ particle, $S_\pi=0$. Therefore, the total initial angular momentum $J_i\equiv J_\pi=L_\pi+S_\pi=0$. By conservation of angular momentum, the total final angular momentum of the $e^-$ and the $\bar{\nu}_e$  is $J_f=L_f+S_f=0$, where $L_f$ and $S_f$ are the total orbital angular momentum and the total spin angular momentum of the $e^-$ and the $\bar{\nu}_e$ . Therefore, consistent with $J_f=0$, the possible values of $L_f$ and $S_f$ turns out to be $L_f=0,S_f=0$ and $L_f=1,S_f=1$. But we also know that the electron and the neutrino are emitted with opposite helicities. But if $S_f=1$, it is not possible that the neutrinos are always emitted with opposite helicities?

Comment: $L_f=1$ does not happen for back-to-back decay products: it is not an option.

Comment: @CosmasZachos How do we argue that properly? Since in the rest frame of the pion, the net linear momentum vector of the decay products is zero, the final orbital angular momentum vector must be zero? I am not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure outside the realm of the explicit calculation, but the overlap of the wavefunctions of the products goes like $r^L$, and this is a very short distance process...

Comment: in your notation, how can a fermion, defined as spin 1/2,  have $S_f$     equal to  1?

Comment: @annav It is the total spin angular momentum of the electron and the neutrino, as stated.

Comment: Then , if it is total and I did not read correctly, as Cosmas said the angular momentum of a decay  to two particles at the center of mass of the parent has to be back to back by momentum conservation, so no "orbital" angular momentum as theta is zero : definition of angular momentum http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/amom.html

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/526766/what-does-the-phrase-s-wave-resonance-mean).